# Call DocumentDb stored procedure from .Net with parameters.

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Calling the sproc works fine, but I can't seem to pass a parameter to it. It works as expected from within the Azure portal, but not when called from .net.

```
documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKeyAdmin);
var sproc = documentClient.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(_companyCollection.StoredProceduresLink, "select * from root r where r.id = \"testSproc\"");
var result = documentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("dbs/GypNAB==/colls/GxpNAKrZMwA=/sprocs/GxpNAKrZMwxxxxAAAAAAAgA==/", sproc, "MyParameter");
```

The sproc hasn't really changed

```
function sample(rrid) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT top 1 * FROM  c where c.RRID = "'+rrid+'"',
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody(rrid + 'no docs found!');
            else getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(feed[0]));
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

The output when called from .net is "[object Object]no docs found!" I would expect [Object Object] to be my parameter value. If I remove the parameter restriction, I get a proper result set back. Also if I run it with the parameter in azure, I get a proper result set back.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter for `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync()` (`sproc`) is mapped to the 1st parameter in the stored procedure - which is why the `rrid` is showing up as `[object Object]` in the output.

Try running:

```
var result = documentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("dbs/GypNAB==/colls/GxpNAKrZMwA=/sprocs/GxpNAKrZMwxxxxAAAAAAAgA==/",  "MyParameter");
```

Comment: Ug, thanx. Guess I was basing my code off a bad example. Maybe you can explain then, I've seen a few examples that do Select * from sproc name first. Is that supposed to be used to get the sproc ID out or what is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: When DocumentDB was released, it required all resources to be referenced by a system-generated `_self` link... which may be what older samples are based off. Roughly half a year ago, routing by user-defined `id` - which makes querying resources by id redundant.